# Pass string from another screen to another

Tags: android, flutter, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to pass subjectCode value from my reusable widget to my subject.dart here is what io have tried

Rwusable widget future

```
class SubjectCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  final String source;
  final String subjectNo;
  const SubjectCard({super.key, required this.link, required this.source, required this.subjectNo,});

@override
  State<SubjectCard> createState() => _SubjectCardState();
}
class _SubjectCardState extends State<SubjectCard>{
  String subjectName = '';
  String subjectCode = '';
  String profesor = '';
  String day = '';
  String start = '';
  String end = '';
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getSubjectsFromDatabase();
  }
  Future _getSubjectsFromDatabase() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subjects").doc("subject list").get().then((snapshot)async{
      if(snapshot.exists){
        setState((){
          try {Map<String, dynamic> docData = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            subjectCode = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["code"];
            subjectName = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["subject name"];
            day = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["day"];
            profesor = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["professor"];
            start = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["time start"];
            end = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["time end"];
            } on StateError catch(e) {
            print('No nested field exists!');
          }      
        });
      }
    });
    // final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.snapshot;
  }
```

Subject.dart

```
  String linkImage(subjectCode){
    if(subjectCode == "THEN"){
      link = "assets/images/MajorApp Icon Design 1.png";
    }else if(subjectCode == "CSDC"){
      link = "assets/images/MajorApp Icon Design.png";
    }
    return link;
  }
```

`SubjectCard(link: linkImage(subjectCode), source: '', subjectNo: 'SUBJECT 3'),`

I am trying to pass the asset path and determined by subjectNo input EX SUBJECT 3

Answer (score 0):

there is several ways, first with callback :

```
typedef OnSubjectCodeLoaded = void Function(String SubjectCode);

class SubjectCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  final String source;
  final String subjectNo;
  /// callback when data sucessfully fecthed from db
  final OnSubjectCodeLoaded onSubjectCodeLoaded;
   ......
  Future _getSubjectsFromDatabase() async {
  ...............
  subjectCode = (docData[widget.subjectNo] as Map<String, dynamic>)["code"];
  //pass your callback data
  onSubjectCodeLoaded(subjectCode);
  .......
```

or save it variable globally, listen to it with help of state management package like `riverpod` or `bloc`